# How to override method with generics?

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to override the *UpdateCommandByGenerationMethod* method in PIGenerator graph.

[image]

Acumatica gives a blank template as follows :

```
public delegate BqlCommandWithParameters UpdateCommandByGenerationMethodDelegate(BqlCommandWithParameters cmd);
[PXOverride]
public BqlCommandWithParameters UpdateCommandByGenerationMethod(BqlCommandWithParameters cmd, UpdateCommandByGenerationMethodDelegate baseMethod)
{
  /* */
  return baseMethod(cmd);
}
```

This will publish fine w/out error. But when I load the screen. I get an error :

***Method PX.Objects.IN.PhysicalInventory.BqlCommandWithParameters UpdateCommandByGenerationMethodTSiteIdField,TInventoryIdField,TSubItemIdField,TLocationIdField is a generic method definition***

**Description**: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:** System.ArgumentException: Method PX.Objects.IN.PhysicalInventory.BqlCommandWithParameters UpdateCommandByGenerationMethodTSiteIdField,TInventoryIdField,TSubItemIdField,TLocationIdField is a generic method definition

The actual method signature in Acumatica is as follow :

```
protected virtual BqlCommandWithParameters UpdateCommandByGenerationMethod<TSiteIdField, TInventoryIdField, TSubItemIdField, TLocationIdField>(
BqlCommandWithParameters cmd)
    where TSiteIdField : IBqlOperand
    where TInventoryIdField : IBqlField
    where TSubItemIdField : IBqlField
    where TLocationIdField : IBqlField
{
    ...
}
```

So how do I fix the declaration of the delegate method ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From last attempt and a talk with someone from Acumatica i don't believe it is still possible to PXOverride a method with with Generics. Would be interested if anyone has found a solution however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to PXOverride a method if it uses generics